# Changing elements within a div makes other elements to change location

Tags: html, css

I am having problems so I have made the code for my List items which is the menu bar on top. I added a picture, but when I did that the list items position moved downwards instead of to the right. I tried to set them position absolute but that didn't work.

HTML:-

```
<div id="header">
            <img  class="quote" src="images/quote.png"/>
            <ul>
                <li class="li">
                    <a href="store.html">Online store </a>
                </li>
                <li class="li">
                    <a href="beauty.html">Beauty </a>
                </li>
                <li class="li">
                    <a href="discover.html">Discover</a>
                </li>
                <li class="li">
                    <a href="men.html">Men</a>
                </li>
                <li class="li">
                    <a href="women.html">Women</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:-

```
#header{
    background-color: #262626;
    height: 90px;
    width: ;
    position: relative;
}
#header ul{

}
#header ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: right;
}
#header ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffe6;
    font-family: medieval;
}
#header img{
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to look like?

Comment: Do you want the menu bar at the top with the image underneath?

Comment: try something as jsfiddle to create something online. moreover, I understand you want your picture as a background of then this should be in your css instead.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/d4371r1b/ UL is a block level element and by defauly anything above it will make it break into a new line

Comment: Oh the image is suppose to be like a logo, but when i added it the list items went far down where they are suppose to be. my list items are floated to the right, and the logo to the left, i want them to be on a line equal to eachother if u get what i mean, but insted the list items are far down ..

Comment: Actually i just fixed the issue :D... heres the code  #header img{
 width: 200px;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 float: left;
}  just had to add float left =P